# Proper solution to handle genders

Tags: magento

i'm creating a big online clothing shop using magento and i was wondering - is there any good solution to handle genders in magento? I need to be able to add products to Male or Female gender but also to some categories like pants, hats or jackets. Categories are the same for both genders so using Gender as top-level category and clothing-categories as gender sub-categories would be a bit redundant i think.

Any ideas or tips would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen Magento stores where Male/Female are the top level categories, and it works well because generally the first thing customers would like to do is see only Male/Female items.

Another alternative is to create a new "Select" attribute for gender (Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes) and set a gender for all products.  Then you could set up top level categories for Jackets, etc and allow customers to filter by gender using the layered navigation.

Comment: Great answer to the question!

Comment: this solution looks interesting! However, i'm quite new to magento and the shop i'm working on has a really custom theme in which i'm not able to set up layered navigation. Can you tell me what would be the URL i.e. for products from category T-SHIRTS (www.domain.com/t-shirts.html) with gender MALE choosed ? I just don't know the magento URL scheme

Comment: You'll create an attribute called gender (or similar) with values for "Male", "Female", etc (or Mens/Womens whichever you'd prefer).  Generallt the layered nav will use URL's like the following...  www.domain.com/t-shirts.html?gender=123  The 123 in the end is the internal numeric id of the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Given your category tree is the same, and gender is equally appropriate as an attribute of a product as it is a category - it would make sense simply to use attributes to facilitate it. Otherwise you will have a needless duplication of category tree.

Using a multiple select attribute for "gender" with two options "Male/Female" - you would be able to have the 1 to many, 1 to 1 relationship that you need for the products.

Then it is just a case of adapting your menu to suit. You could easily just append

```
&gender=male
```

to your menu URL and it would pre-select the appropriate filter from the layered navigation.

#### The better way

Would be to add a custom extension to "shop by X", gender in your case - then customise your top nav to reflect the shop by Male/Female options. Then you would have cleaner SEO urls to capture keyword phrases for "Mens suit jackets" by having a landing page for such.

Planning this element of your store is critical and the implementation even more so, to make it both scalable and a positive shopping experience for your customer.